# Integration test not running with flavor

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I am running integration tests with Flutter application. I am also using `Flavors` in Flutter. The problem is it is giving me this error:

```
Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under /home/khamidjon/Desktop/android_flutter_projects/my-project/build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

1. I have put all the dependencies inside `pubspec.yaml`.
2. created 3 directories as docs mentioned: integration_test/, test_driver/, test/

test_driver/integration_test.dart:

```
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';

Future<void> main() => integrationDriver();
```

integration_test/main_functions_test.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

    
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets("failing test example", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    expect(2 + 2, equals(5));
  });
}
```

Then run following command in terminal:

```
  flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/main_functions_test.dart
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using flavors, you need to specify which flavor you want to run your app:

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/main_functions_test.dart --flavor development
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to fix the same problem.

1. Create new scheme in Xcode for running integration tests (in my case it named e2e):

[image]

2. Add a configuration:

[image]

3. Update `Build Configuration` of the added scheme:

[image]

4. Specify the path to integration tests:

[image]

5. The `integration_test/app_test.dart` should look like this:

[image]

6. Run with the next command:
   `flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart --flavor e2e`